# Vue files on Laravel does not reflect changes after pulling changes from repository on production server

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nginx, digital-ocean

im workin with LARAVEL and vue. i'have launched a project on digital ocean using ubuntun and nginx. Since the launch i'have add more features. Today i pulled those change on the production server, but they do not appear on the browser..

Using nano i'have chechked all the files, and yes, the files have changed but they do not reflect on the browser.

I'have used
npm run dev, npm run watch
php artisan config:cache, php artisan cache:clear but yet it doesnt seems to work
any idea ?

Comment: my component called "Documents" was not reflecting changes. I renamed it to "DocumentSummary" and it started working fine. weird.

Answer (score 4):

Before you push your updated Vue files you need to run `npm run prod` to prepare your assets as production ready.

Laravel uses `mix` to compile assets: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix

Now you have your freshly compiled assets in your `public/` directory, therefore you can pull to digitalocean machine. But now the browser might still be using cached asset (if name stays same, browser doesn't fetch same asset again for a while)

So, Mix Versioning comes to help: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting

In your `webmack.mix.js` file you need to add `.version()` at the end of mix piping. End result will be something like this;

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .version();
```

As you want to use versioning, now you need to resolve asset urls with `mix(...)` instead of `asset(...)` in your blade files;

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Now whenever you compile your assets, mix will assign them new version numbers and will at them to end of assets' urls in your blade. Browser will understand there is a update in file (because of a different version number) and will fetch updated asset.

Comment: Thanks for replying, im about to check it out

Answer (score 2):

Did you clear your browser's cache?

If you are working with Vue and/or Sass and therefore your files are changing from time to time, I suggest you to use `mix()` instead of `asset()` for cache busting. Otherwise all of your users will have to delete their cache (this is obv. not a good approach)

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting

Comment: Maybe i should try this approach. First of all im ussing asset().  I give it another shot, first cleared everyting using php artisan commands, then executed npm run dev and everything started working. Anyway i should try ussing mix. Thanks for replying

Comment: @jeremiassgg, let me know the outcome :)

Comment: Its working like a charm. Thank you so much

Comment: If possible, could you accept my answer and maybe also upvote it. I would appreciate it

Comment: Sorry for anwsering late, at the time i asked the question i was knew to stackoverflow so i could not upvote your answer